# Why the hamming distance between 2 similar images is more focusing on the bigger part with ORB?

Tags: image-processing, match, opencv3.0, orb, opencv, python

As I know, the hamming distance is better if it is small.While when I run this code:

```
# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
print(matches[0].distance)
print(matches[len(matches)-1].distance)
good=[]
# filter the good matches by distance in [min,2*min]
# set a limited min 30 avoid the min being too closer to 0
# TODO why '>' is more accurate
for obj in matches:
    if(obj.distance>2*max(matches[0].distance,30.0)):
        good.append(obj)

print(len(good))
```

The more similar two images is, the bigger the output is.Why?If the images is similar, shouldn't the result be more focusing on the small part?

Comment: You are comparing descriptors and matches, not images, so you may want to reword that last sentence. 2 very different images can have few very matching descriptors, as very different images  may have similar structures (e.g. sky in landscape images). That doenst mean that the images are the best match, only that the images have areas, or features, that are very similar

Comment: Thanks for answering.I'm a little confusing. Does the more very match descriptors there are, the more similar two images are?Can't the descriptors describe the features (or areas) rather than just structures?

Comment: I mean that the result caused by my code looks like that the bigger  the obj.distance is , more similar the features between two images are

Comment: Tehre may be a bug. You are sorting matches, but not obj.distances, and comparing them. Not a big expert in python though

Comment: @AnderBiguri You're right .I made a ridiculous mistake.The bad match's lowest distance multiplying 2 is almost big enough to over all the distance in it.Thanks a lot.